# Looking into what's wrong with the Quarkus 1.2.Final and Kogito 0.7.1 project

Tags: quarkus, dmn, kogito

I am forced not to use Kogito parent bom for reasons I can't explain. 
So I got a Maven project which is based on Quarkus 1.2.Final and Kogito 0.7.1, and was able to resolve all the version mismatch issues. The code compiles but fails to run tests. It throws the following error and I do have kogito-ruleunits in my dependencies.

```
9:18:53,268 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.kogito.deployment.KogitoAssetsProcessor#generateModel threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/kogito/rules/impl/AbstractRuleUnits
```

I have publish the project on github : https://github.com/mravi786/junk/tree/master/dingo-dmn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue because you use a version incompatible with Quarkus 1.2.1.

I don't know exactly why you can't use the Kogito BOM but there's definitely some artifact that is not the right version.

Update: Quarkus 1.2.x supports Kogito 0.6.x. Due to the tight integration between the two, you cannot upgrade Kogito like this. If you absolutely need Kogito 0.7.1, you can start playing with Quarkus 1.3.0.Alpha2. We will release CR1 soon and the Final a week after that.

Comment: I updated my answer based on what I have seen in your repo.

Comment: I did try dependency:tree and it looks as i expected, updated with all 0.71 versions. The code compiles, its the junits that fail..

Comment: See my answer above. Your issue is that Quarkus 1.2.x does not support Kogito 0.7.1. So either you downgrade Kogito to 0.6.1 or you upgrade Quarkus to 1.3.